# hive, how to use "extended" and "formatted" when describing table?

Tags: hive

When typing

```
describe extended table_name,
```

the output is massed up. So is there a way to show these infomation elegently?

Answer (score 1):

show `elegantly` is something depends on your requirement. Both of your commands will show same result but differently.
`describe extended` - This will show table columns, data types, and other details of the table. Other details will be displayed in single line.
`describe formatted` - This will show table columns, data types, and other details of the table. Other details will be displayed into multiple lines.

You can also use `describe table`  to just get column names and data types.

EDIT :
The partition info in formatter option is displayed in the data in a hierarchical manner. You can look into the attached screenshot. In the example, source system is used a partition so you can see it is shown along with data type.
[image: Partition info]

In describe extended option, same parameters are put into single line so you can see it there.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But the 2 commands show different results. For example ,there is no partition info in "desc formatted table_name".

Comment: no, they both display partition info. in formatted option, it displays in the data. Pls refer to the EDITed answer.